# How to get value from return / callback aggregate in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to get value from return / callback aggregate in Node.js?

```
function getAmount(vcode,callback){db.get().collection('general_journal').find({coa_code:vcode}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, result) {             
    if (err) return callback(err);                  
    callback(null, result);                 
})}
function getlist(callback) {
 db.get().collection().find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {           
    var vData = [];
    if (err) return callback(err);  
    result.forEach(function(row){
      vData.push({coa_code:row.coa_code,amount:getAmount(row.coa_code)})
    })              
    callback(null, vData);                  
  })}

getlist();
```

Please help to solve this problem, because the Amount value is always undefined, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because `getAmount` is asynchronous, you'll have to use `Promise.all` to wait for all rows' requests to resolve before calling `getList`'s callback. Change `getAmount` to return a `Promise` rather than using a callback to make things easier:

```
function getAmount(vcode){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.get().collection('general_journal').find({coa_code:vcode}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, result) {             
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    })
  });
}
function getlist(callback) {
  db.get().collection().find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    // Map each row to a Promise that resolves to an object:
    Promise.all(
      result.map(({ coa_code }) => getAmount(coa_code).then(amount => ({ amount, coa_code })))
    )
      .then(vData => {
        callback(null, vData);
      });
  })
}
```

Comment: Did it work for you? If so, you can consider marking the answer as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved